# Sequelize generates wrong SQL statements in findAndCountAll() when using TypeScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm using the following code for a REST route using expressjs, I'm also using TS in my project.

```
const { limit, skip } = req.query as any;
  let data: {
    count: number;
    rows: Array<Eintragung>;
  };

  try {
    data = await Eintragung.findAndCountAll({
      limit: limit as number,
      order: [['Id', 'DESC']],
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
```

The problem with the code is sequelize generates an SQL statement with the limit looking like this `LIMIT '25'`, though in MySQL/MariaDB this is not a valid statement since 25 should be number not a string.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''25'' at line 1
```

The same problem happens when I use `findAll()`.

If I hardcode the limit to 25 like this

```
data = await Eintragung.findAndCountAll({
  limit: 25,
  order: [['Id', 'DESC']],
});
```

the SQL statement gets generated correctly and the query works.

I'm wondering what I did wrong with TypeScript, I obviously have to declare the `limit` variable as number because sequelize only accepts numbers as limit.

I'm using sequelize 6.3.5 and MariaDB 10.3.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by wrapping the limit variable in `parseInt()` like so:

```
data = await Eintragung.findAndCountAll({
   limit: parseInt(limit),
   order: [['Id', 'DESC']],
});
```